# Visual Studio 2012 code definition window does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide

I've downloaded and installed VS2012 Express and for some reason the code definition window doesn't exist.There's no such item in the view menu.I've tried the shortcuts (CTRL + \ , D) which should enable the CDW but i got an error message "The Key combination "CTRL + \ , D) is not a command"

Was the CDW removed in VS2012 or is there a way to reset or re-enable it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, You should reinstall fresh one.

Comment: Installed again (Tried both the online and the offline versions) tried to repair , still doesn't work...It's strange because in the manual it clearly states that the CDW exists in this version.I know they removed it starting from 2013 but should work in 2012... I don't get why is such a great feature so taboo ?

Comment: Can you analyze the it? <https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1624176/code-definition-window-not-working-in-vs2015-release-version-was-fine-in-rc>

Comment: I get an error every time i try to open the link

"The system has encountered an unexpected error. We apologize for the inconvenience. The issue will be addressed as quickly as possible."

Comment: Well , it seems it just doesn't work... I can live without it but it was a very nice feature it's a pity they removed it.